# Creating a dynamic shape with pure CSS3

Tags: html, css, transform, css-shapes

I am very proficient in CSS but I can't for the life of me figure this one out.

I need to recreate a number of shapes in pure CSS (if possible) for a project. What makes it even more harder is that I need the shapes to use a background images. I have tried numerous CSS3 properties such as skew, transform, rotate etc... however none has worked so far. Skew got me closest but the background and it's contents where skewed. I tried setting an image inside the div and giving it opposite properties to the div skew which straightened the image but then I couldn't position the image correctly.

Is it possible in anyway to recreate this using CSS?

[image]

Even if someone can help me find the right property to use so I can research how it'll be done that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use the canvas object in html5 or does it have to be strictly CSS3 on an object?

Comment: Canvas could work, I haven't touched on it much though. Any links? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult shape to make this one. You can create this shape using `clip-path` but I'm afraid the support is not amazing for this property.

See the support [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Now here is an example of the shape with a background.

```css
.shape {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(24% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 40%);
  clip-path: polygon(24% 0, 95% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 40%);
  background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/640/39/1629941.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give a diamon so you can tweak it to get your shape :

```
#diamond-narrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 70px solid red;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
#diamond-narrow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px; top: 70px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 70px solid red;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/